# How to make find_or_initialize case insensitive on a Postgres DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 3.2 app I have a Post model that belongs to a Category. In the new post form is a text field for assigning a category or creating a new category.

It works via the following method on the Post model

```
def category_name=(name)
  if name.present?
    post_cat = category.find_or_initialize_by_name(name) 
    if post_cat.new_record?
      post_cat.save(:validate => false)
      self.category = post_cat
    else
      self.category = post_cat
    end
  end
end
```

This is more or less working, but is case sensitive. For example, the database now contains records for "Featured", "featured" and "FEATURED" categories.

How can I make the above `find_or_initialize` function behave as though it were case insensitive. I am using a Postgres database, and I have a suspicion that this is not quite as easy as "making `find_or_initialize` case insensitive".

I'm grateful for any advice as to best practice, what to consider, and useful references.

Comment: why don't you just do a `category.find_or_initialize_by_name(name.downcase)`?

Comment: thanks 23tux, that's a good idea, but what if my categories require some unusual capitalization. For example, one of the categories may be named after a brand e.g. BrandName and should be displayed with this capitalization in the views. If downcasing, this customization would be lost, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refer to your comment above: Maybe you could add a second field, containing the value of the string which is displayed to the user, and `find_or_initialize` by the name column:

```
post_cat = category.find_or_initialize_by_name(name.downcase)
post_cat.display_name = name if post_cat.new_record?
```

So the second line ensures, that an existing record doesn't get overriden by another user, who tries to add categories like `bRandnAmE`. The only pitfall I see is, that the first user, who creates the category, has to spell it correct.

Comment: Thanks @23tux this is a great idea! I've added a `lookup_name` to my database (this way I don't need to replace all my existing `Category.name` code in the views). I see your point about the first user needing to spell the item correctly, but there are ways for edits to be made to categories, so capitalization can be changed subsequently. Many thanks!